# How to implement the client code for an Abstract Factory?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, factory, abstract-factory

I'm having a hard time understanding the implementation of client code with the factory method. I understand the overall use of Abstract Factories but my issue is I want the Factory to figure out the correct object to instantiate at runtime, but every implementation I see involves passing an enum or some other value to the constructor.

This is my current design

```
using System;

namespace FactoryTest.Jobs
{
    public class ExchangeProvider1 : IExchangeProvider
    {
        public void Buy()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Buying on Exchange1!");
        }
    }
}

using System;

namespace FactoryTest.Jobs
{
    public class ExchangeProvider2 : IExchangeProvider
    {
        public void Buy()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Buying on Exchange2");
        }
    }
}

  public interface IExchangeFactory
{

}

   public interface IExchangeProvider
{
    void Buy();
}

  public class ExchangeFactory : IExchangeFactory
{
    public static IExchangeProvider CreateExchange<T>() where T : IExchangeProvider
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public static IExchangeProvider CreateExchange(string exchangeName)
    {
        return (IExchangeProvider) Activator.CreateInstance<IExchangeProvider>();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm trying to have the factory build the correct provider based on details the user fills out in a web form. On hitting create I want to the factory to instantiate the correct provider and run the correct logic. But with this implementation Im forced to do something like

```
var provider = ExchangeFactory.CreateExchange<Exchange1>();
```

When I really want to be able to get the Exchange Type from the user at runtime from the web form and pass it to the factory

```
//Receive IExchangeType from user submitting web form
var provider = ExchangeFactory.CreateExchange<IExchangeType>();
```

Is this possible? I'm wondering (or the correct solution), or if I'm on the right track but am definitely hindered by a gap in knowledge.

Comment: How can you, as a human, tell which exchange to create based on the web form?

Comment: I think I've just been overthinking it. I'm now seeing likely the correct solution is to have a drop down, and then pass the object type selected in the form to the constructor. Is this the correct way to use a Factory in a context like this?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by this. Isn't the point of the factory so that you don't have to change the factory? I was also under the impression that magic strings were frowned upon in factories. But I guess it would make sense in the context of POST data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments the other answer is a violation of [O/C Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) (and a bit of Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)) of [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

A more dynamic approach is to inject all instances of the exchange and pick the correct one. Bellow example is based on the class name (not full-qualifed name, but that cane easily be changed).

```
public interface IExchange
{
    void Buy();
}

public class Exchange1 : IExchange
{
    public void Buy() => Console.WriteLine("Buying on Exchange1");
}

public class Exchange2 : IExchange
{
    public void Buy() => Console.WriteLine("Buying on Exchange2");
}

public interface IExchangeFactory
{
    IExchange CreateExchange(string exchangeName);
}

// All exchanges are instantiated and injected
public class ExchangeFactory : IExchangeFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IExchange> exchanges;

    public ExchangeFactory(IEnumerable<IExchange> exchanges)
    {
        this.exchanges = exchanges ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exchanges));
    }

    public IExchange CreateExchange(string exchangeName)
    {
        var exchange = exchanges.FirstOrDefault(e => e.GetType().Name == exchangeName);
        if(exchange==null)
            throw new ArgumentException($"No Exchange found for '{exchangeName}'.");

        return exchange;
    }
}
```

It can easily be extended by registering further implementation with the DI, w/o any code changes on the factory

```
service.AddScoped<IExchange, Exchange3>();
service.AddScoped<IExchange, Exchange4>();
```

In high performance scenarios (a couple of 1000 requests **per second**) where the injected services are scoped/transient or the memory/GC pressure on creating this extra instances is high, you can use the provider pattern to only create the exchange that's really required:

```
public interface IExchangeProvider
{
    IExchange CreateExchange(string exchangeName);
}

public class Exchange1Provider : IExchangeProvider
{
    public IExchange CreateExchange(string exchangeName)
    {
        if(exchangeName == nameof(Exchange1))
        {
            // new it, resolve it from DI, use activation whatever suits your need
            return new Exchange1();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class Exchange2Provider : IExchangeProvider
{
    public IExchange CreateExchange(string exchangeName)
    {
        if (exchangeName == nameof(Exchange2))
        {
            // new it, resolve it from DI, use activation whatever suits your need
            return new Exchange1();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class LazyExchangeFactory : IExchangeFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IExchangeProvider> exchangeProviders;

    public LazyExchangeFactory(IEnumerable<IExchangeProvider> exchangeProviders)
    {
        this.exchangeProviders = exchangeProviders ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exchangeProviders));
    }

    public IExchange CreateExchange(string exchangeName)
    {
        // This approach is lazy. The providers could be singletons etc. (avoids allocations)
        // and new instance will only be created if the parameters are matching
        foreach (IExchangeProvider provider in exchangeProviders)
        {
            IExchange exchange = provider.CreateExchange(exchangeName);

            // if the provider couldn't find a matcing exchange, try next provider
            if (exchange != null)
            {
                return exchange;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException($"No Exchange found for '{exchangeName}'.");
    }
}
```

This approach is similar to the first, with the exception that you are extending it by adding new `IExchangeProvider`s. Both approaches allow you to extend the exchanges w/o a change on `ExchangeFactory` (or in high performance scenarios `LazyExchangeFactory`)

Comment: Thanks :) I'll have to consider this in my own code more.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you shouldn't tell the factory which *concrete type* to create. You should give it the information it needs to make that decision by itself. Now, I'm not saying that this can't be a 1:1 relationship, just that the caller shouldn't tell the factory to make a specific concrete type.

Imagine you have a `Student` object with a `Grade` property. You also have a factory which produces `ISchool`, and concrete implementations `ElementarySchool`, `MiddleSchool`, and `HighSchool`. Now you could have 3 methods: `CreateElementarySchool()`, `CreateMiddleSchool()` and `CreateHighSchool()`, but then the caller has to decide which one it wants.

A better approach is to have a method which uses some information to create the the school. For example: `CreateSchoolForGrade(grade)`. Internally, the factory will have logic which works out which concrete type matches the grade.

In your case, if you have a set of 2 types to choose from on a webform, you could accept the type (let's say the options are Empire or Rebels). You could have an enum:

```
public enum Faction
{
    Empire,
    Rebels
}
```

and then a factory method:

```
public IFaction CreateFaction(Faction faction)
{
    switch (faction)
    {
        case Faction.Empire:
            return new EmpireFaction();
        case Faction.Rebels:
            return new RebelsFaction();
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now, imagine that you retire EmpireFaction, replacing it with EmpireFactionV2. You only need to modify your factory, and the caller doesn't care:

```
public IFaction CreateFaction(Faction faction)
{
    switch (faction)
    {
        case Faction.Empire:
            return new EmpireFactionV2();
        case Faction.Rebels:
            return new RebelsFaction();
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh okay this makes a lot more sense. I appreciate the answers.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I was able to successfully implement my code with your method. 

The web form grabs the id of the exchange, casts to an enum and passes the enum to the factory, which instantiates the correct provider. :) thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: Isn't this a violation of SOLID's Open/Closed principle? Open for extension, closed for modification. The cleaner approach is to inject an enumerable of possible classes and pick the one. Unless you have to full qualifed name, it would require each implementation to have a check if it applies to the parameters, which may violate single responsibility principle (SRP of SOLID). So you usually have lightweight providers with the logic to determine if it applies or not and if so, returns/creates an instance of the class ...

Comment: ... as done in [ASP.NET Core's Model Binders](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/2.2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/ModelBinderFactory.cs#L167-L175)

Comment: @Tseng Perhaps you could add an answer to that effect? I would like to see your approach to the same scenario.